# Kotlin/Java merge same ids in another class RecyclerView

Tags: java, android-studio, kotlin, android-sqlite

trying to build a simple bet app with sql db. For a bet each player can choose Yes (1) or No (2).

```
class Bet(val id: Int, val betid: Int, val playername: String, val playerbet: Int, val result: Int)
```

Want to merge all Bet instances with same betid in another class so RecyclerView can display it in 1 row:

```
class BetRec(val id: Int, val betid: Int, val playerbets: Map<String, Int>, val result: Int)
```

Right now I have

bet1 = Bet(1, 1, "player1", 1, 0)

bet2 = Bet(2, 1, "player2", 2, 0)

bet3 = Bet(3, 1, "player3", 1, 0)

bet4 = Bet(4, 1, "player5", 2, 0)

Goal is:

BetRec(1, 1, mutableMapOf<String,Int>("player1" to 1, "player2" to 2, "player3" to 1, "player5" to 2), 0)

to display it in a RecyclerView row like

betid 1    Yes: player1, player3 No: player2, player 5

Maybe there's another way to display it in 1 row but I'm very beginner and don't know better.

Hope u can help. Enjoy your day!

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking here. Are you looking for help to write code that converts a `List<Bet>` into a `BetRec`? Or are you looking for help regarding a SQLite query?
Also, is it guaranteed that `betid` and `result` are the same in the whole list? And how do you find the correct `id` value for `BetRec`?

Comment: Basically converting List<Bet>`val playername: String, val playerbet: Int` to List<BetRec>`val playerbets: Map<String, Int>` so I can display it in 1 RecyclerView row. The `result` supposed to match playerbet or not. The `id` of `BetRec` does not really matter (doesnt have to match Bet id).

Answer (score 0):

I think `associate` may be what you're looking for here:

```kotlin
val map: Map<String, Int> = playerBets.associate { it.playername to it.playerbet }
```

Then you can use it to build whatever you need.